# Can't Paste any Texts

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, clipboard

I just download some Desktop Environment for my Kali Linux. Then at second usage (after reboot), I tried to copy MAC Address in terminal. But when I click Paste, the text can't even show in my screen. I've tried it with Right-Click and install Parcellite, but nothing happen. I tried too to go back to my preinstalled DE (Gnome), but also nothing worthy.

Details:

```
OS : Kali Linux
Kernel : x86_64 Linux 4.14.0-kali3-amd64
DE : XFCE
WM : Xfwm4
CPU : Intel Celeron N2840 @ 2x 2.5 GHz
RAM : 2 GB
DualBoot with Windows 10
```

Comment: Is Kali your first Gnu/Linux OS? Is it your main desktop OS?

Comment: Yeah, the GRUB always automatically running Kali instead Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry I was miss-under stood. I am asking in Kali the first Gnu/Linux OS that you have used. I.E. have you used a different Gnu/Linux in the past, or is this your first. **I am not asking about boot order**.

Comment: It means, yes.. Kali Linux is my main Desktop..

Comment: Do not use Kali as a desktop OS. It is not made for such a use. You should use a desktop oriented OS such as Ubuntu, Fedora, Mint, MacOS, Windows 10 ... Anything but Kali which is more than a pain in the A... when you're a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it myself. I just go arround the Wiki and found that XFCE desktop has occured some bugs, especially about Clipboard System. So I just remove XCFE desktop and Parcellite, then reboot my Desktop.